# Let $p \in \lbrace2,3,4,...\rbrace$. Suppose that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $p \mid xy$, then $p \mid x \vee p \mid y$. Show that $p$ is prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I'm studying for an upcoming exam and came across this question in my textbook. I'm assuming the easiest way to approach this proof is by contradiction. I don't have much so far, I just suppose that $p$ is not prime, but cannot find a way to reach a contradiction from this where $p$ has to be prime based on the fact that $p$ divides $x$ or $p$ divides $y$.

Comment: Hint: if $p$ isn't prime, then $p=xy$ for $x,y<p$. Can $p\mid x$ or $p\mid y$?

Comment: That should be an answer Wojowu.

Comment: That is a great hint, thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your definition of *prime number*?

Comment: @CameronBuie From our textbook, "A prime number is any p in N such that p!=1 and for any a,b in N if p=ab then either a=1 or b=1.

Comment: Gotcha. The reason I ask is that many texts use as a definition the very property you were asked to prove!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent to the statement you want to prove is its contrapositive:

> If $p$ is not prime, then there are $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ where $p|xy$ but $p$ divides neither $x$ nor $y$.

Try some examples.  Take $p=6$ and see if you can find $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ where $6|xy$ but $6$ divides neither $x$ nor $y$.  Then try it with $p=8$ and $p=12$.  Try to think of a general strategy for finding such $x$ and $y$ once you are given composite $p$.  Then ask yourself whether this strategy would work when $p$ is prime.  (If the theorem is correct, the strategy *shouldn't* work.)  That should give you some ideas of how to proceed.